# Get alias name dynamically in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table named tblalias.which is having two columns cid, description

```
cid                  description
1                    Employee
2                    Join Date
3                    Retire Date
```

Like this three record is present

Now I have another table `tblemployee`. I want to write a query for `tblemployee` to get record but alias name for that query I want should come from `tblalias`

```
select nama as Employee,
       joindate as "Join Date",
       retiredate as "Retire Date" 
from tblemployee
```

If I change value is `tblalias` table to my select query should return new value as alias is it possible if yes how please help me

Comment: BTW: what do you mean by 'dynamically' ? Please explain.

Comment: dynamic mean the alias name in my select query will come from tblalias table that is not hard code

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is with dynamic SQL. First fetch the alias names then build the final SQL and execute it.

There is no way doing this with a single "hardcoded" statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want spaces in names you should quote them. (spaces in names is generally a bad Idea, but that's another matter)